# Performing a RACSignal Synchronously

Tags: ios, objective-c, watchkit, reactive-cocoa

I'm currently working on a WatchKit app and I'm currently having an issue with this given method:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary*)userInfo reply:(void (^)(NSDictionary* replyInfo))reply
```

My networking client is built on top of Reactive Cocoa and everything is performed asynchronously. For this method in the AppDelegate I need to fire off the reply response before the method finishes so I'm wondering if theres anyway to block the method from finishing until the RACSignal has been completed (subscribeCompleted).

Any help is great!

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep! You're looking for [`waitUntilCompleted:`](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/blob/8daf10ec80a340dea0c956e0e13c58219282d22b/ReactiveCocoa/RACSignal%2BOperations.h#L443).

Comment: i think this might be causing a deadlock with AFHTTPRequest operation. Seems to freeze up when trying to use it with that

Comment: fixed by setting a different completionQueue on AFHTTPRequestOperation